# How to configure static /22 IPs on main network device in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

Set up a new Ubuntu 16 64bit Server. Need to bind the full /22 IPv4 as static. I can only ping .2 from the outside, but not the remainder and I'm stuck here.

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.16.2
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        network xxx.xxx.16.0
        broadcast xxx.xxx.19.255
        gateway xxx.xxx.16.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        dns-search domain.com
```

This method won't work

```
root@server:~# ip addr add xxx.xxx.16.1/22 dev eno1
root@server:~# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:ed:fb:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.16.2/22 brd xxx.xxx.19.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.16.1/22 scope global secondary eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d6be:d9ff:feed:fb8a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:ed:fb:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:ed:fb:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:ed:fb:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

root@server:~# ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.xxx.16.2  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast xxx.xxx.19.255
        inet6 fe80::d6be:d9ff:feed:fb8a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d4:be:d9:ed:fb:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28742  bytes 1879979 (1.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 989  bytes 112470 (112.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to add each of the addresses in the /22 range to the `eno1` interface?

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind one address to an interface, it won't accept a network.  If you want to bind more you need to create virtual interfaces like so:

```
sudo ifconfig eno1:0 123.123.16.3/22 up
sudo ifconfig eno1:1 123.123.16.4/22 up
```

Do that 1024 times and you have your network set up.  I suggest writing a script and adding it to your startup.  Check the man page for ifconfig if you need to do more configuration.

You can also configure virtual interfaces (also known as a network alias) in your /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto eno1:0
iface eno1:0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.16.3
....
auto eno1:1
iface eno1:1 inet static
address xxx.xxx.16.4
```

and repeat.  You are probably better served writing a custom script, managing that huge file is going to be a nightmare if you need to change anything a simple find / replace won't handle.